# Google services slow/won't load on home wifi across all devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Youtube is slow and google music songs will not load for all devices. These devices work normally on other wi-fi and 5g. This problem has been consistent for at least 1 week.

If you need any more info, let know. I am not a networking expert, but am comfortable with windows and linux's command line interfaces.

tracert 8.8.8.8 gets 2 "Request timed out"s

youtube and google play music appear to be the only problems (I have youtube red if that matters).

I have tried:

- Running internet speed tests (http://internethealthtest.org/ 100 Mbps
  up and down all five steps)
- Multiple devices with different operating systems.
- Resetting the router and changing the password.
- Disconnecting all devices except for my desktop (I read chrome cast
  can cause this, so I left my only device that cannot cast).
- Connecting through my companies VPN on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a network or hardware issue at all. Google Play Music and YouTube Red are both paid Google services. Maybe a silly question, but is your Google account and payment arrangements up to date? Make sure all looks good at accounts.google.com

The other "sledgehammer" solution as always: Clear cache/app data, uninstall, reboot, reinstall.

Comment: My accounts all look good, and my devices work on any network other than my home network, so I doubt it is related to the cache/app data. Since it affects all devices on my home network, but those devices work on other networks, I think it is my home wifi.